# How do I troubleshoot this api call?

Tags: react-native, axios

I have the following code...

```
async function GetFirstAssessment() {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get('http://192.168.254.10/App/GetFirstAssessment/');
    return response.data;
  } catch (error) {
    alert('error: ' + error);
    console.error(error);
  }
};
```

It's been working fine for some time, but suddenly it no longer works and eventually times out. Or I don't even know if it "times out" since I believe the default timeout for axios is 0 but eventually it does error with the message "Error: Network Error". I've also added a picture of the stack trace but I don't think it's helpful.

I can put the url in a browser and it returns the json I'm expecting, so the problem is definitely not on the server side. I am testing from an android device connected via usb and developing with cli (not expo).

If there is any other information I can provide please let me know... not sure what to do next because this really makes no sense. I would wonder if it was a security issue except that it was working perfectly earlier. Also I have updated some other code that calls this, but even after reverting I still have the same problem... and seeing as how it is making it to the catch, I don't see how any other code could be affecting this.

I did just install the standalone react native debugger. I believe it has worked since I installed it, though I'm not 100% certain on that. Still doesn't work after closing it.

I set a break point in the server code on the first line of the api method, but it doesn't get hit. Not sure how to troubleshoot further up the chain though. I also just thought to check fiddler and it doesn't show any request coming in, though I honestly don't know if it should normally or not.

[image]

Comment: You are using ip, if your router is DHCP maybe it change so you need to update it.

Comment: @anthonywillismuñoz That thought occurred to me, but unfortunately was not the case. And running the link from a browser window wouldn't work either in that event.